# What causes harsh noise during TX/RX on VHF radio?

Tags: radio-communications

I am running some trial radio test on PAE VHF main radio and during TX from ATC there is harsh noise at the background even though TX is 5/5. Likewise for the incoming RX from aircrafts. So I swapped the main radio with the standby radio but is giving me same results. I want to know what is causing this noise and how to eliminate it.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you're using ATC transmissions, this doesn't seem to be an aviation question. You might do better on [electronics.se]

Comment: Noise on comms is a common aviation problem @ReddHerring, and for me it's on topic.

Comment: @GdD "on topic" is defined by what is written here https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and not what someone thinks might be remotely on topic. If that were the case this place would be a madhouse. :) This is an electronics/communications issue with VHF radios of any kind, not an aviation-specific issue.

Comment: @JuanJimenez There are VHF, UHF and HF radios on board of aircraft. There are also hydraulic systems and electrical systems on board of aircraft. While hydraulics, electricity and radio transmission are all part of physics, they are part of aviation as well.

Comment: @Koyovis The scope of this site does not cover hydraulics, electricity or radio transmission. This one is about specific subjects in aviation and there are other StackExchange sites that can address those subjects. If you don't agree you can always submit a proposal to change the statement of scope.

Comment: @JuanJimenez You may consult posts like [this ome](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3354/21091).

Comment: By "harsh noise" do you mean white noise or some other type of noise, like crackling, etc?

Comment: This would be closed as off topic if posted on Electrical Engineering SE as it is a *usage* or *repair* question and not a *design* question.  Look for local issues, for example if the noise correlates with the engine being on/off and RPM it could be a problem with noisy power.  If the source were external and in-band, a handheld or radios in another aircraft adjacent on the ramp would experience it, too.  If both radios are of the same design its vaguely possible some extremely strong out of band transmission could exploit a susceptibility in the architecture of both.

Answer (score 1):

If the transmit signal is strong the Signal-to-Noise Ratio is high, which would mean that the noise that you hear is not background white noise filtered through the VHF frequency band. First thing I would look for is an active noise transmitter on the band, which would only be present in a limited set of frequencies.

Hard to say from behind the keyboard what causes the noise that you hear, suggestions for troubleshooting:

- Is the noise present at all Xmit frequencies?
- Does it diminish if you move away from your present position?
- Does your squelch setting help at all?

Comment: In fairness, the received signal can be strong while the S/N ratio is low. This can happen, for example, if you have a high noise floor where the receiver is located. The transmitted power would seem to have little bearing here, except that with a high transmit power, you'd be able to reach farther before the S/N ratio drops to any given value with any given noise power at the receiver location.

Comment: Indeed, this answer fundamentally misunderstands the term "Signal-to-Noise Ratio" - the intent might have been to suggest that the AGC would have ramped down the gain.